# Why is a static lifetime asked for and how can I narrow it when dealing with rust Iterators?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm obviously (by the question) new to Rust. In the following example, the compiler asks for the two borrows in `x` of `g(...)` to outlive `'static`. I don't understand why that is and how I could narrow it. I don't actually know the lifetime of the slices (though I do know that the inner is as long as the outer). What am I missing? I read the lifetime explanation in the Rust book and several SO posts but while lifetimes are frequently asked about no discussion really answers this point (or I don't see the match).

Here the problematic code in simplified form:

```rust
pub trait A <X> 
where X: Copy
{
    fn f(&mut self, x: Box<dyn Iterator<Item=&[X]>>) -> Option<X>;

    fn g(&mut self, x: &[&[X]]) -> Option<X> {
        self.f(Box::new(x.iter().copied().cycle()))
    }
}
```

rustc 1.66.0

Comment: Please post the full error from `cargo check` in the next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because `dyn Trait` actually has a lifetime attached, which can be elided, and that would be `'static`. So when you write `dyn Trait` the compiler sees `dyn Trait + 'static`. Since you are attempting to pass your `x.iter().copied().cycle()` into the function, that means that the resulting `Iter` must have a `'static` lifetime. If you are explicit with the lifetimes, you will see that it compiles just fine:

```rust
pub trait A <X> 
where X: Copy
{
    fn f<'a, 'b>(&mut self, x: Box<dyn Iterator<Item=&'b[X]> + 'a>) -> Option<X>;

    fn g<'a, 'b>(&mut self, x: &'a [&'b [X]]) -> Option<X> {
        self.f(Box::new(x.iter().copied().cycle()))
    }
}
```